# prolog - replace only first founded element in a list

Tags: prolog

how can in replace only the first element founded in a list?
I have this example:

```
replace(_,_,[],[]).
replace('-', NewChar, ['-'|T], [NewChar|T2]):- replace('-', NewChar, T, T2).
replace('-', NewChar, [H|T], [H|T2]):- H \= '-', replace('-', NewChar, T, T2).
```

And the result is:

```
?- replace(-,o,[x,x,x,-,-,-],X).
X = [x, x, x, o, o, o].
```

but should be:

```
X = [x, x, x, o, -, -].
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Right here: `replace('-', NewChar, ['-'|T], [NewChar|T2]):- replace('-', NewChar, T, T2).` after you've matched the character once, you keep going recursively. Don't do that.

Comment: If i try to replace `replace('-', NewChar, ['-'|T], [NewChar|T2]):- replace('-', NewChar, T, T2).` with `replace(C, NewChar, [C|T], [NewChar|T]).` and then query `?- replace(-,o,[x,x,x,-,-,-],X).` i get, in SWISH, `X = [x, x, x, o, (-), (-)]` and not `X = [x, x, x, o, -, -]` as expected (`-` in bracket). Instead ECLiPSe gives me the correct result (without brackets on the last two `-`). Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: `(-)` is just putting a grouping around `-` because `-` is sometimes used as an operator. it's not an "issue". It's like saying `(1)` instead of `1` in an expression. If you want SWISH to give you more consistent looking results, put `-` in quotes everywhere `'-'`: `replace('-',o,[x,x,x,'-','-','-'],X).`

Answer (score 0):

For didactical purpose, it's good practice to craft - and consequently debug - such basic utility predicates. Once you grasped the basic, consider the 'swiss army knife' of list processing - append/3.

```
replace_first(OldEl, NewEl, OldList, NewList) :-
  append(H, [OldEl|T], OldList),
  append(H, [NewEl|T], NewList).
```

I think it make apparent the relational approach that is best suited to Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

```
?- select(-,[x,x,x,-,-,-],o,Y).
```

and the result is:

```
Y=[x,x,x,o,-,-].
```

see [SWI Prolog - Select](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/4)